# How can i center several <div> in middle of page that are in another <div>?

Tags: html, css

I tried to use several ways for
example with transform translate -50% and top and left 50% child
display absolute and parent alternative but it didn't work.

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    gap: 1rem;
    position: relative;
}
.widget img{
    width: 4rem;
}
.widget p img {
    width: 1.25rem;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.widget a img {
    width: 1rem;
}
.widget {
    width: 100%; background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
    padding: 25px; border-radius: 1rem; 
        
}
.widget button {
    padding: 8px 24px;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
.widget button img {
    width: 1.25rem;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="widget"><img src="/src/invest-svgrepo-com.svg" alt=""><br>
            <h2>$4,500</h2><br>
            <p>Earned this month</p><br>
            <p><img src="/src/up-arrow-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="">+6.5% more than last month</p><br>
            <button>Earning <img src="/src/right-arrow-svgrepo-com.svg" alt=""></button>
        </div>
        <div class="widget"><img src="/src/rocket-svgrepo-com.svg" alt=""><br>
            <h2>25</h2><br>
            <p>New Sales</p><br>
            <p><img src="/src/up-arrow-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="">+16.22% more than last month</p><br>
            <button>Earning <img src="/src/right-arrow-svgrepo-com.svg" alt=""></button>
        </div>
        <div class="widget"><img src="/src/meeting-svgrepo-com.svg" alt=""><br>
            <h2>7</h2><br>
            <p>New Members</p><br>
            <p><img src="/src/diagonal-arrow-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="">-19% than last month</p><br>
            <button>Earning <img src="/src/right-arrow-svgrepo-com.svg" alt=""></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
</body>
```

Comment: The point of the requirement for you to post more text is to persuade you to _improve_ the quality of your question, not wreck it by adding junk to an already poor post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code hope it fix your issue :)

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    gap: 1rem;
    position: relative;
}
.widget img{
    width: 4rem;
}
.widget p img {
    width: 1.25rem;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.widget a img {
    width: 1rem;
}
.widget {
    width: 100%; background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
    padding: 25px; border-radius: 1rem; 
        
}
.widget button {
    padding: 8px 24px;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
.widget button img {
    width: 1.25rem;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="widget"><img src="/src/invest-svgrepo-com.svg" alt=""><br>
            <h2>$4,500</h2><br>
            <p>Earned this month</p><br>
            <p><img src="/src/up-arrow-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="">+6.5% more than last month</p><br>
            <button>Earning <img src="/src/right-arrow-svgrepo-com.svg" alt=""></button>
        </div>
        <div class="widget"><img src="/src/rocket-svgrepo-com.svg" alt=""><br>
            <h2>25</h2><br>
            <p>New Sales</p><br>
            <p><img src="/src/up-arrow-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="">+16.22% more than last month</p><br>
            <button>Earning <img src="/src/right-arrow-svgrepo-com.svg" alt=""></button>
        </div>
        <div class="widget"><img src="/src/meeting-svgrepo-com.svg" alt=""><br>
            <h2>7</h2><br>
            <p>New Members</p><br>
            <p><img src="/src/diagonal-arrow-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="">-19% than last month</p><br>
            <button>Earning <img src="/src/right-arrow-svgrepo-com.svg" alt=""></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add width and height in class `.flex-container`. According to what you need to centering the element based on display, you can use the `vw` or ***virtual-width*** and `vh` or ***virtual-height*** to set the width and height. Then add some flex attribute to centering it.

```css
 .flex-container {
    display: flex;
    gap: 1rem;
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: I dont know that , thank you for your help i had learn something new :)

Answer (score 0):

There are different methods

I start by using `body{margin: 0 auto;}`

If that doesn't work, you can always experient with `justify-content: center;` or `align-content: center;`